# Adding a settings screen to my iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In applications like `CNN int`, in the `Settings` Tab of the `iPhone`, you could click on `CNN` and access a view which has the settings to the application;

Like if to `Logout` of `Facebook`,`Twitter` and the `version`.

How can i get this application setting view in the `Settings` Tab for my application ?

For example something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple and can be achieved with the addition of a single .plist file to your project. The Apple documentation is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html). You're looking for a "Settings Bundle".

Answer (score 0):

I used [this nifty little tool](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/), it's free and quick.

You'll might also need the tutorial [Johann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/638040/johann) suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the settings bundle or if you want your app settings in the app its self you could have a look at something call InAppSettingsKit. I have been duly informed that this is a good option as it gives more freedom with your settings.